# Rules and syntax of exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have three yes/no questions about exceptions in C++:

1. Does an exception class have to be derived from the exception class defined in the standard library?
2. If an exception is thrown in a function, say, `f()`, but not handled there, the exception is propagated to the function that called `f()`. Is it true?
3. An exception object can be a user-defined type or any type that is built-into C++. Is this true?

Comment: (1) no, it *should* be derived, by convention and common sense, but the language does not require it. (2) yes. this is the basic idea of exceptions. (3) yes. see 1.

Comment: An exception object can be an instance of any type that is copyable.

Comment: If answer of 2 is yes, why the following code gives me error?


#include <iostream.h>
  void f()
  {
     try
  {
   throw 20;
    }


  }

int main ()
{
 f();
   catch (int e)
  {
    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

Comment: @sattar_kuet.bd, Because the `try` should be in `main`. Or do you mean the error from using the extremely old, deprecated, non-standard `<iostream.h>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1) Does an exception class have to be derived from the exception class defined in the standard library?

Practically anything can be thrown as an exception, including fundamental types (e.g. `int`) or C-strings. If the exception you throw is of class-type, there are only the conditions defined in 15.1/5 C++11:

> When the thrown object is a class object, the copy/move constructor and the destructor shall be accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided (12.8).

> (2) If an exception is thrown in a function, say, `f()`, but not handled there, the exception is propagated to the function that called `f()`. Is it true?

If it is thrown from inside a `try...catch` clause, and there is a `catch` statement defined that matches the exception type (or an ancestor of it in the class hierarchy), the exception will be caught. Otherwise (or if caught and rethrown from within the catch-statement), it will indeed be propagated to the calling function, and handled there in the same way recursively.

> (3) An exception object can be a user-defined type or any type that is built-into C++. Is this true?

Yes, except as said under (1) above; if of class-type, copy and move constructors and destructor must be accessible. (They don't have to be user-defined, but they must be accessible, i.e. not private.)